# PiP avoid activity recreation when entering

Tags: android, picture-in-picture

Is there a way to avoid the activity recreation when changing over to a picture in picture window?

Basically I call it like this:

```
@Override
protected void onUserLeaveHint() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 24 && isInFullscreen) {
        MainActivity.this.enterPictureInPictureMode();
    }
    super.onUserLeaveHint();
}
```

The activity always reloads, which results into longer waiting times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the docs-  add this to the activity in your manifest:

```
android:resizeableActivity="true"
android:supportsPictureInPicture="true"
android:configChanges=
    "screenSize|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout|orientation"
```

See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/picture-in-picture.html for more detail